# python как вставить все строки в таблицу psql

Tags: python, база-данных, psycopg2, psql

Есть 2 файла. **Первый файл** парсит сайт и создаёт таблицу, **второй файл** принимает переменные первого и вставляет в базу данных. К переменным первого файла относится **one_row[0], one_row 1** и т.д., переменная **one_row[0]** содержит в себе столбец из первого файла (см. скрин ниже: например "Logic Error"), каждой переменной принадлежит по столбцу. Всё что я пробовал, заносит только последнюю строчку таблицы из первого файла. У меня не получается написать программу так, чтобы заносила все строчки в базу данных.

**Вопрос: как вставить все строчки который считывает первый файл в базу данных?**

Вывод первого файла:

[image: Информация, которую выводит 1 файл]

Кусок кода второго файла:

```
try:
# Подключение к существующей базе данных
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres_user",
                              # пароль, который указали при установке PostgreSQL
                              password="password",
                              host="localhost",
                              port="5432",
                              database="my_postgres_db")

# Курсор для выполнения операций с базой данных
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Распечатать сведения о PostgreSQL
print("Информация о сервере PostgreSQL")
print(connection.get_dsn_parameters(), "\n")
# Выполнение SQL-запроса
# Вставка в БД ------------------------------->
insert_query = "INSERT INTO table1 (bug_group, bug_type, file, function, line, path_lengt) VALUES ( '{}', '{}', '{}','{}', '{}', '{}');".format(one_row[0], one_row[1], one_row[2], one_row[3], str(one_row[4]), str(one_row[5])) #работает
cursor.execute(insert_query)
connection.commit()
cursor.execute("select * from table1;")
# Получить результат
record = cursor.fetchall()
print("Вы подключены к - ", record, "\n")
```

Второй файл заносит в БД только последнюю строчку вывода из первого файла (см. вывод первого файла). Как занести все строчки в базу данных psql?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что `one_row` это одна запись (строка) таблицы а `one_row[n]` это поле (столбец) этой записи?

Comment: Да, столбец. Код приложу ниже:
https://pastebin.com/kq2yTQPY

Comment: Я решил проблему. Чуть позже приложу решение. Спасибо за ответ!